# Two figures with the x axis frame of exactly the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to make two separate figures which will be than pasted together in such a way that they share the x axis. I don't want them to overlap, one must stay on the top and the other on the bottom, but with the same x axis. I tried to do it by setting the same `figsize`, then controlling the margins using `plt.subplots_adjust()`, for example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1=plt.figure('fig1',figsize=(6.4,4.8))
ax1=fig1.add_subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.15, right=0.95, top=0.9, wspace=0, hspace=0.5)

fig2=plt.figure('fig2',figsize=(6.4,4.8))
ax2=fig2.add_subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.15, right=0.95, top=0.9, wspace=0, hspace=0.5)
```

Then they might have different labels in the y axis. Unfortunately, when I try to paste them using GIMP, I see that their x axis size is very slightly different. How can I control the x axis size in such a way that there is no risk of having this problem?

Comment: Why not create one figure with two subplots? Problem should be solved then. The code that you show should create two identical empty figures, so please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @rinkert 
T.Y. That could work as well. I know how to make a figure of several plots combined, but how can I indicate that I do not want margins between the figures and the vertical frames of the top figure are just a continuation of the ones of the bottom figure?

Comment: `fig, (ax1, ax2)  = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(6.4,4.8), sharex=True); fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest
Yes. That's what I needed. T.Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `add_subplot`, try `add_axes` as shown in the example below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.1,10,10)
y1 = x*x
y2 = np.exp(-x/3)

fig =plt.figure('fig1',figsize=(6.4,4.8))

ax1 = fig.add_axes((0.1,0.1,0.8,0.4))
ax2 = fig.add_axes((0.1,0.5,0.8,0.4))


ax1.plot(x,y1,color='Red')
ax1.set_xlim(0,10)
ax2.set_xlim(0,10)
ax2.plot(x,y2,color='Blue')
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the x axes do not coincide in your example. As you can see, `0` and `10` are not perfectly aligned in the two figures.

Comment: Just add `ax2.set_xlim(0,10)`